# Using par parameters with ggplot2

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm trying to set my default parameter using `par()` function to be used when I plot graphs using ggplot2.

For example setting a white background or color palette. however, it does not work with ggplot2!

Does `par()` only function on basic plots or I'm doing something wrong?

For example:

```
opar <- (par)
par(bg = "white")
```

Then I try ggplot

```
ggplot(melt(raw1), aes(x=reorder(NA.), y=value, fill=variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge')
```

Then I get the same gray background of ggplot (I understand that I can use `+ theme_bw()`)

Comment: `par` is for base graphics. you have to use the various `theme()` parameters to change ggplot graphics aesthetics. Do a `?theme` in an R console to see the parameters and, perhaps, study up in the [ggplot2 wiki](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki).

Comment: The base graphics uses plot, points, lines commands, which uses par (per @hrbrmstr)